# I am looking for a Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla plugin

Tags: wordpress, cms, joomla, drupal, plugin

I am looking for Wordpress, Drupal or Joomla plugin similar to [this one](http://www.eurocoffee.gr/content.php?cat=338), with product list and PDF attachments.

Does anyone know if there is such a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal you need the cck module and imagecache if you are using Drupal 6. No module needed if you use Drupal 7 (don't know if imagecache is in a standard Drupal 7 build).

You can just make a content type "product", add the fields you want, scale the imagefield with imagecache and you can create the look by making a template tpl.php for that content type, or use views.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need any plugins for Wordpress to achieve that. Just look up [customized Wordpress loop](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/archives/2008/04/13/define-your-own-wordpress-loop-using-wp_query/) or you can try post thumbnail plugin (there are many, [here's an example](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-thumbnail/))